# print string with bios interrupt 0x10

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bios

I want to print a string using bios interrupt 0x10. But I get only a blue fiel, without letters in it. Maybe I habe a problem by adressing my string.

Edit: I have two code files. The first is written on the first sector of a floppy. It copys the second sector from the floppy to the memory (starting at 0x5000) and jump to 0x5000. Here is my second file, where I should print my string.

```
[BITS 16]
org 0x5000

sect2:
    mov ah, 0x03    ;get curser position
    mov bh, 0x00    ;page number

    int 0x10

    mov ax, 0x0500 
    mov es, ax
    mov bp, bsy1msg 

    mov ah, 0x13            ;write string
    mov al, 0x01            ;update cursor after writing
    mov bh, 0x00            ;page number
    mov bl, 0x1F            ;atributes
    mov cx, bsy1len         ;number of characters in string

    int 0x10

end:
    jmp end

bsy1msg db 13,10,"BSY1 via INT 0x10"
bsylen equ $ - bsy1msg
```

Comment: Try with `mov ax,cs` instead of that constant to load ES. I'm not entirely convinced your assumption there is valid.

Comment: with 'mov ax, cs' I get the same result

Comment: maybe something with 'org 0x5000' ?

Comment: Are sure DH/DL (row/column) have sane values?

Answer (score 1):

The `org` directive doesn't cause the program to be loaded at a specific physical address, it informs the assembler to assume that the program is loaded that far into the code segment.

So for example, the value of `sect2` is not zero, it's `0x5000`.

Setting `es` to `0x500` would make it start at the physical address `05000`, but that's not where the program is. You want the extra segment to start at the same point as the code segment, as the `bsy1msg` label is relative to the code segment (and has the value `0x501d` if I calculated correctly).

```
push cs
pop es
```

Comment: My program is at 0x5000. As a total beginner I forgot to add this to my question.

Comment: @spitzbuaamy: Then `es` should still be the same as `cs`, i.e. zero.

Answer (score 1):

An address is expressed as `segment:offset`, and the physical address is calculated as `segment*16+offset`. So `0x0500:0` refers to the same physical address as `0:0x5000`. If your program is located at the physical address 0x5000 then `CS:IP` should be `0x0500:0` or `0:0x5000`. The string is located at the physical address 0x501d. Since you specify `org 0x5000` nasm will assume the offset of bsy1msg to be 0x501d. Which means that the segment has to be 0 (`0*16+0x501d = 0x501d`). Or, if you set ES to 0x0500 (directly or by copying CS), you need to either omit org 0x5000 or subtract the offset from BP (`mov bp,bsy1msg-sect2`) to get the right physical address (`0x0500*16+0x001d = 0x501d`).