# BIOS interrupt print string

Tags: assembly, nasm, bios, 16-bit, real-mode

I managed to print a string in the BIOS (tested on QEMU), but I want to adapt it into a function because i have a couple more strings i want to print but i cant just keep pasting the same code or itll become unintelligible

Here is what I tried:

```
PrintString:
    mov ah, 0xe
Next:
    mov al, [si]
    inc si
    or al, al
    jz Exit
    int 0x10
    jmp Next
Exit:
    ret

Boot:
    mov si, Message
    call PrintString
    jmp $

Message db "Test Test Test", 0
```

basically i move pointer to the first character into si then i go trough each character until i get 0, at which point i return

then a jmp $ to keep me in a loop

but when tested in qemu, it only prints "S"

I actually also have a piece of code that changes the color of the screen trough interrupt 10 ah 9, but it also seems to not work when i try to print a string this way, so that might tell you something about what is wrong, but I am a beginner

any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Show complete code. As it is, the entry point seems to be the `PrintString` when you want to start at `Boot`. So move that to the top. Also make sure you initialize the `ds` register in accordance with the `org` in use.

Comment: Damn. I didnt even think of that, man. thanks for this insanely quick fix. also what is the ds register and why would i initialize it in accordance to the org? right now the code works fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [print string with bios interrupt 0x10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27332266/print-string-with-bios-interrupt-0x10)